# Jenkins parametrized job failed "Connection to remote server failed [403], waiting to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

Retry attempt #5 out of 5
FATAL: Max number of connection retries have been exeeded.
org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.exceptions.ExceedRetryLimitException: Max number of connection retries have been exeeded.
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.utils.HttpHelper.sendHTTPCall(HttpHelper.java:569)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.utils.HttpHelper.sendHTTPCall(HttpHelper.java:564)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.utils.HttpHelper.sendHTTPCall(HttpHelper.java:564)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.utils.HttpHelper.sendHTTPCall(HttpHelper.java:564)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.utils.HttpHelper.sendHTTPCall(HttpHelper.java:564)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.utils.HttpHelper.sendHTTPCall(HttpHelper.java:564)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.utils.HttpHelper.tryCall(HttpHelper.java:603)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.utils.HttpHelper.tryGet(HttpHelper.java:625)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.RemoteBuildConfiguration.doGet(RemoteBuildConfiguration.java:955)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.RemoteBuildConfiguration.getRemoteJobMetadata(RemoteBuildConfiguration.java:1146)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.RemoteBuildConfiguration.performTriggerAndGetQueueId(RemoteBuildConfiguration.java:679)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.RemoteBuildConfiguration.perform(RemoteBuildConfiguration.java:646)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.RemoteBuildConfiguration.perform(RemoteBuildConfiguration.java:612)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:21)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:808)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:516)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1889)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:100)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:433)
Finished: FAILURE

it should trigger another parametrized Jenkins job remotely, for which url is provided in configurations